# Solving a congruence relation of the first degree (step-by-step solution?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

Solve the following congruence: 
$508x + 124 \equiv 0 
\pmod{668}$.                                     Note the solution in a numeral system of the lowest non-negative remainders of the aforementioned module.

Comment: What is the aforementioned module?

Comment: Is there any particular significance to this congruence?

Answer (score 2):

First, it is equivalent to the congruence (dividing by the g.c.d. of the coefficients):
$$127x+31\equiv0\pmod{167}\iff127x\equiv -31\pmod{167}.$$
Next step: find the inverse of $127\bmod 167$.  This is done through the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which yields the coefficients of a *Bézout's relation* between $127$ and $167$:
$$-71\cdot 127+54\cdot 167=1$$
so the inverse of $127$ is $-71$, and the solution is
$$x\equiv -71(-31)\pmod{167}=2201\equiv 30\pmod{167}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Cancel by $4$:
$$127x +31\equiv 0\pmod{167}$$ 
subtract 127 by 167 
$$-40x +31\equiv 0\pmod{167}$$
multiply by 4
$$-160x +124\equiv 0\pmod{167}$$
so
$$7x-43\equiv 0\pmod{167}$$
multiply by $24$
$$168x\equiv 1032\pmod{167}$$
so
$$x\equiv 30\pmod{167}$$

So $x = 167t+30$, $t\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: In your second line, you should have $-40x + 31 \equiv 0 \pmod{167}$ since $127 - 167 = -40$.

Comment: thx for soullutions, but which is correct? :-) first or second? two examples, two solutions :-(

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Bernard is great, and I would just add one thing to it. We find that we need $x\equiv 30\pmod{167}$, but I believe you're looking for solutions modulo $668$. Since $668=167\cdot 4$, our four solutions will be $30+167k$, for $k=0,1,2,3$. This gives us:

$$x\equiv 30, 197, 364, 531\pmod{668}$$